# Basic JavaScript threading

Tags: javascript, multithreading

So im working on a function that needs a variable called PagePic, that is initialized in another function called getPage(), as seen here:

```
      function somefunc(){
getPage();
addMarker({ coords:{lat:Lat,lng:Long},iconImage:PagePic)}
}
```

Somewhere up in the code:

```
function getPage(){
 FB.api('/*******?fields=picture,events',  function(response) {

             PagePic = response["picture"].data.url
}
```

However, getPage does not finish in time, so addMarker is called without an actual value for iconImage. 
From  the testing ive done, seems like getPage starts working only when addMarker finishes, but i could be wrong in this. Ive tried a custom sleep() function, and it didn't help. From google i saw that browsers only have a single thread, and im planing on moving the project im working on to mobile in the future. So is there a solution that i can implement when i work on the mobile version, or can i fix it here somehow? Thanks!

Comment: Use async await in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is not multithreaded. What you're dealing with is called asynchronous, not multithreaded. There are many ways to go about this: callbacks, promises, async.

For a basic idea, do something like this (with callbacks):

```
function cb(pagePic) {
  addMarker({ coords:{lat:Lat,lng:Long},iconImage:PagePic)};
}

function someFunc() {
  getPage(cb);
}

function getPage(callback){
  FB.api('/*******?fields=picture,events',  function(response) {
    PagePic = response["picture"].data.url;
    callback(PagePic);
}
```

EDIT:
It's not that getPage() isn't finishing in time. It *is* finishing. But callbacks go on the event loop and only execute after all synchronous code is finished. Here's an example:

```
console.log("a");
setTimeout(console.log.bind(this, "b"), 0);
console.log("c");
```

0ms timeout. This should print "a" "b" "c", right? Not quite.